# Apostrophe s in XML string file

Tags: java, android, xml, string, apostrophe

I tried two ways according to documentation of android like this :

```
<string name="tc">use of any of Company\'s services</string>
<string name="tc">use of any of Company's services</string>
```

but it gives error :

```
AAPT: error: unescaped apostrophe in string
```

I'm using Android studio 4.1.2
Please help me out with this.

Comment: First approach is correct , make sure you don't have strings defined in other resources file

Answer (score 2):

`&apos;` is the usual way to escape a `'` in XML. Maybe that will work for you instead?

Maybe interesting as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/9712270

Answer (score -1):

The first approach is the correct one

```
<string name="tc">use of any of Company\'s services</string>
```

It's just needed this "" before the apostrophe.
If there aren't other strings with this problem, it should works.

Comment: Sorry this is not the way to escape in xml, you use &apos;

Comment: Thank you for your comment, for me it works with        \  before the apostrophe.

Comment: The thing is @Lucas it might work in your situation because whatever parser you're using forgives it, but that doesn't make it right, and it's possible you will bump into a parser that doesn't accept it at some point.  I don't want other readers to get the wrong idea and use \ which may give varying results when the upvoted answer is already correct, use &apos;  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: Ok, thank you for explain me that